# Can I write API contract tests (consumer driven) using RestAssured framework?

Tags: rest-assured, web-api-testing

I wanted to implement some contract tests and was looking at different frameworks like Pacto, Postman etc. I am familiar with RestAssured so just wanted to ask if it is possible to write api contract tests using Restassured and are there any good examples of it ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article about that : https://hmh.engineering/how-to-write-and-validate-pact-contracts-using-junit5-and-restassured-72b578e7dd65